# Get notifications using Twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-gem

I'm trying to get Twitter notifications using Twitter gem. 
I'm using the method notifications from Twitter::User but the value is always `false` even though I receive emails from Twitter about those new notifications :

```
twitter = current_user.get_twitter_api
@twitter_user = twitter.user(current_user.authentications.find_by_provider("twitter")['username'])[:notifications]

def get_twitter_api
   twitter_info = self.authentications.find_by_provider("twitter")
   twitter_api = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => twitter_info['fb_token'],:oauth_token_secret => twitter_info['uid']) if twitter_info
   return twitter_api
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling notifications as a method on the user object, for example:

```
@twitter_user = twitter.user(current_user.authentications.find_by_provider("twitter")['username']).notifications
```

I remember using this gem and finding geo coordinates on an individual tweet by doing:

```
tweet.geo
```

Comment: it's returning `false` - I think it's the same as what I'm doing right now

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn't have an API endpoint for receiving notifications, assuming that by notifications you mean the content at http://twitter.com/i/notifications. The notifications value that you can in the API response is actually

> notifications
>
> Boolean
>
> Nullable. Deprecated. May incorrectly report “false” at times. Indicates whether the authenticated user has chosen to receive this user’s tweets by SMS

that's from https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users